# Can you predict a Pokemon's next evolutionary stage's CP?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am buddying with my 1036 CP Weepinbell and I will evolve it when I get enough candies. Will it stay close to that level CP? Is where a way to know what it will be? What about HP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You can use tools like [this one](https://pogotoolkit.com) to find what your next evolutionary stage's CP will be based on what the current evolutionary stage's CP is.